# Run apache/php/nginx in background Docker container

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I am trying to run a docker container running `Apache and PHP` or `PHP-FPM`.

Like that

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7.0-apache
```

And it attaches STDIN/STDOUT to my host machine

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name my-apache-php-app -v "$PWD":/var/www/html php:7.0-apache
```

Seems to work fine, but I read that

> By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root
>   process used to run the container exits.

Does it mean if I start container from remote ssh connection and then close it, the docker container will stop ?

I am building my custom docker image based on the

> library/php/

And I need my image to start automatically in background, not in foreground.

How can I get this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits.

The root process in this context is the root process *inside* the container, not the root process used to `docker run` the container. This process is typically an ENTRYPOINT or CMD in the Dockerfile. For Nginx, often you see something like:

`ENTRYPOINT ['nginx', '-g', 'daemon off']`

This container would exit when the nginx process exits (which shouldn't be immediately unless your nginx configuration is bad, or some other error kills it).

If you were to have an ENTRYPOINT like this:

`ENTRYPOINT ['nginx', '-t']`

Then the container would test any nginx confs it found, give you the result in STDOUT, and exit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case is it fine to use `-d` option, will it satisfy my requirements ?

Comment: @bxfvgekd I would say yes, it should be fine.